# Autocomplete search in angular 14 using prime-ng autocomplete is always gives result for 1 less typed character

Tags: angular, rest, autocomplete, primeng

I am using prime-ng autocomplete to show search results in a div. The issue is that although the search works but it is always 1 keypress behind. SO if i search for John it would give me result for Joh only. I can see in the log that all four characters are being passed to the service and then service gives back correct result but result that is being displayed is always the last result from the service not the current.

This is the html:

```
 <p-autoComplete [showTransitionOptions]="'0ms'" [hideTransitionOptions]="'0ms'" [delay]="100"
            [(ngModel)]="value" data_eusw_control="quickTagSearch"
            [suggestions]="quickTagsDetailsService.quickTagsFilteredList" field="displayName" [minLength]="1"
            (completeMethod)="searchForTags($event)" scrollHeight="300px" [multiple]="false"
            (onSelect)="tagsSelected($event)" [style]="{'width':'100%'}" [inputStyle]="{'width':'100%'}"
            [showClear]=true  data_eusw_control="quickTagSelect_dropDownSelect"  [appendTo]="'autocompleteContainer'">           
          </p-autoComplete>



<div id="autocompleteContainer">
    <ng-template pTemplate="item" ngFor let-quicktag [ngForOf]="quickTagsDetailsService.quickTagsFilteredList"
    let-index="index">
      <div class="p-2 mt-2 font-bold rounded-lg card body border-1" (click)="quicktagSelected(quicktag,index)"
        [attr.data_eusw_control]="'quicktag_'+ index" style="overflow: hidden;">
        <div class="w-full text-sm text-[#ff6c22] font-arial mb-2 ">
          {{ quicktag.tagId }}
        </div>
        <div class="left-0 flex flex-row" style="display: block!important;">
          <div class="px-1 py-1 mb-2 startText" style="float: left; margin-right: 5px;">
            ProjectId:
            <span style="color: #2795bf; font-size: x-small">{{
              quicktag.projectId
              }}</span>
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="configService.config?.businessType === 'legal'" class="px-1 py-1 mb-2 startText"
            style="float: left; margin-right: 5px;">
            PhaseCode:
            <span style="color: #2795bf; font-size: x-small">{{
              quicktag.phaseCode
              }}</span>
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="configService.config?.businessType !== 'legal'" class="px-1 py-1 mb-2 startText"
            style="float: left; margin-right: 5px;">
            Activity:
            <span style="color: #2795bf; font-size: x-small">{{
              quicktag.activity
              }}</span>
          </div>
         
        </div>        
       </div>
    </ng-template>
  </div>
```

This is the code :

```
searchForTags(event): void {
    console.log('event.query : ' + event.query);
    let filtered: QuickTags[] = [];
    if (!event.query) {
      this.quickTagsDetailsService.quickTagsFilteredList = filtered;
    }
    else {
      this.quickTagsDetailsService.quickTagsFilteredList = this.quickTagsDetailsService.getFilteredQuickTags(event.query).slice(0,3);      
    }

  }
```

This is the method from service :

```
public getFilteredQuickTags(query:string): QuickTags[] {
    this.quickTasksService
        .getQuickTagsByUser(this.userService.profile?.userPrincipalName)
        .subscribe((data) => {
            let filtered: QuickTags[] = [];
            let json = JSON.stringify(data);
            let jsonObject = JSON.parse(json);
            let jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonObject.data);
            if (jsonData) {
                jsonData.forEach((element) => {
                    if (element.tagId?.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase()) ||
                        element.projectId?.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase()) ||
                        element.activity?.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase()) ||
                        element.category?.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())) {
                        let quickTag = new QuickTags(element);            
                        filtered.push(quickTag);
                    }
                });
            }
            this.filteredQuickTags = filtered;
        });
    
        return this.filteredQuickTags; 
    }
```

I am new to angular so don't have much idea what i am doing wrong here!! Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the code for `searchForTags($event)`? If you click somewhere on the screen a couple of seconds after you're done typing, does the screen update again?

Comment: I have updated the question to add the code. No the screen does not get updated if i click somewhere else after typing. What i did found out was that screen is getting binded earlier than the service is returning result.

 this.filteredQuickTags=filtered;      in the service is getting exectuted  after the ui is already updated and hence you see last results.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in the `getFilteredQuickTags()` function, you make a server call, which is asynchronous, but you return `this.filteredQuickTags` at the end of the function synchronously.

You can try these changes:

```
searchForTags(event): void {
    console.log('event.query : ' + event.query);
    let filtered: QuickTags[] = [];
    if (!event.query) {
      this.quickTagsDetailsService.quickTagsFilteredList = filtered;
    } else {
      this.quickTagsDetailsService.getFilteredQuickTags(event.query);
    }
}


public getFilteredQuickTags(query:string): QuickTags[] {
    this.quickTasksService
        .getQuickTagsByUser(this.userService.profile?.userPrincipalName)
        .subscribe((data) => {
            let filtered: QuickTags[] = [];
            let json = JSON.stringify(data);
            let jsonObject = JSON.parse(json);
            let jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonObject.data);
            if (jsonData) {
                jsonData.forEach((element) => {
                    if (element.tagId?.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase()) ||
                        element.projectId?.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase()) ||
                        element.activity?.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase()) ||
                        element.category?.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())) {
                        let quickTag = new QuickTags(element);            
                        filtered.push(quickTag);
                    }
                });
            }
            this.filteredQuickTags = filtered;
            this.quickTagsDetailsService.quickTagsFilteredList = this.filteredQuickTags.slice(0,3);  
        });
    }
```

This way the update is made at the end of the server call callback and you use the latest value.